# wellPanel Rshiny cut off by input options when scrolling

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, opacity, rshiny

Rshiny wellPanel opacity issues

How can I ensure my shiny app's wellPanel is not cut off by other elements within the UI?
I'd like the user to scroll and the wellPanel containing the title will act alike a frozen row in excel.

Thank you!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    
    mainPanel(
        div('data-spy'="affix", 'data-offset-top'="1",
            wellPanel(id = "tags", class = "myclass1",
                      
                      tags$style(HTML(".datepicker {z-index:99999 !important;}")),
                      titlePanel(title= strong("title that I don't want cut off")) 
            , width = 12)),
        hr(),
        
        fixedRow(
            tags$style(HTML(".date {z-index:9999}")),
            
            
            column(12, 
                   dateInput("date", 
                             h3("Date:"), 
                             value = "2021-01-01"))   
        ),
        hr(),
        
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        fixedRow( 
            
            
            column(8, 
                   numericInput("room_num", 
                                h3("Number of Rooms"), 
                                value = 0, min=0, max=99))
        ),
        
    ))


server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Just included a sample code thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `fixed` div. The next sibling would then use a `padding-top` to offset the next elements. This approach, however, requires that you specify the `height` and the `padding` explicitely.

N.B. I am also adding the `.container` class to the first row, to get the proper `width` from the bootstrap framework:

```r
library(shiny)

css <- HTML(paste(".fixed { position: fixed; height: 105px; padding-left:0; padding-right: 0 }",
                  ".fixed+.row { padding-top: 107px}", sep = "\n"))

ui <- fixedPage(
   tags$head(tags$style(css)),
   fixedRow(wellPanel(h2("Title")), class = "fixed container"),
   fixedRow(h3("Title"), numericInput("inp1", "Number:", value = 0)),
   fixedRow(h3("Title"), numericInput("inp2", "Number:", value = 0)),
   fixedRow(h3("Title"), numericInput("inp3", "Number:", value = 0)),
   fixedRow(h3("Title"), numericInput("inp4", "Number:", value = 0)),
   fixedRow(h3("Title"), numericInput("inp5", "Number:", value = 0)),
   fixedRow(h3("Title"), numericInput("inp6", "Number:", value = 0)),
   fixedRow(h3("Title"), numericInput("inp7", "Number:", value = 0)),
   fixedRow(h3("Title"), numericInput("inp8", "Number:", value = 0)),
   fixedRow(h3("Title"), numericInput("inp9", "Number:", value = 0)))

server <- function(...) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```